# Do I need to use minifyEnabled true in child library?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have an android project named projectA.

I use compile `project(':projectB')` in `build.gradle` of projectA.

I have use `minifyEnabled true` in projectA.

Do I need `minifyEnabled true` in projectB?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you only need to declare the minifyEnabled true in projectB if you have the proguard rule in the project B. If not, you don't need to do it.

Android Studio provide us the way to define proguard in many project.